# QAC tag is not used according to description

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tag-wiki

We currently seem to have 3 questions with [qac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qac) tag: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747360/qa-c-license-file), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603632/how-to-avoid-bitwise-operations-on-signed-data-will-give-implementation-defined), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983196/qa-c-does-not-give-a-warning-on-multiple-return-statements-in-one-project-but-do). All three refer to [QA-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QA-C) software, not to quasi-algebraically closed fields, as the tag wiki suggests.

Should the description of existing tag be changed, or should a new [qa-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qa-c) tag be created instead (and questions be retagged)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tag wiki was plagiarized (verbatim copy-paste) from Wikipedia, so I hopped into my time machine and prevented it from ever getting approved. It doesn't look like the person who proposed it ever had any involvement with the tag and/or associated questions, so they probably had no idea what the tag actually meant or how to write a good wiki for it, which is why they plagiarized it in the first place.

With that done, the tag was left without a wiki, and thus no ambiguity: all questions with the tag refer to the QA-C static analysis tool, so that's what the tag should be used for. I'm not qualified to write a good tag wiki, either, but I did create an excerpt that at least describes the function of the tag.

I also renamed the tag to [qa-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qa-c), since that's a better match to the actual name of the product.

If there ever comes a time that we need a tag for quasi-algebraically closed fields, then I guess a [qac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qac) tag could be created, but I'm not sure that these are sufficiently programming-related to even merit their own tag here.